# using a select query from 2 views

Tags: sql

there is a sql query problem in which i should find out which users have passed all of the tests.
here are the tables:

ex: nameoftable(nameofcolumns)

**user(userid,password)**

**test(test#,creditpertrue,negperfalse,total,neededcredit)**

*{creditpertrue=points given per a right answer and negperfalse=points taken per a wrong answer
and total=is the total points of a test and neededcredit is the points to pass the test}*

**question(test#,q#,truechoice#)**

**user_test(userid,test#)**

*{this table shows that which user have taken which test(a user can only take a test once)}*

**user_test_question(uesrid,test#,q#,userchoice#)**
*{this table shows the choice of every user in every test and question# which may be wrong or right}*

now the question is this:
**`find out the userid of users that have passed all of the tests.`**

a solution that came to my mind was this:

create 2 views like this:
view1:userid,test#,numberofrightchoices

and

view2:userid,test#,numberofwrongchoices

and then use a select on these 2views and use numberofrightchoices*creditpertrue-numberofwrongchoices*negperfalse>=neededcredit

is it possible?

Comment: How is the user is considered passed a test? just has a testid in the user_test? or the user has all the questions of the tests the user has is truechoices? and what about the neededcredit to do with this? Please explain.

Comment: a user have passed a test when he/she gets the needed credit for a test (numberof(right choices)*creditpertrue-numberof(wrongchoices)*negperfalse>=neededcredit

Comment: Do you want to find the users that have passed all the test they have taken, or only the users that have passed all available tests?

Comment: i need to find the users that have passed all the available tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the query that you need to get a list of users who have passed all the tests would be this:

```
select userid,
from user_test
where userid not in (
    Select 
        userid
    from    
        (select t0.test#,t2.uesrid, neededcredit,
            Sum(case when t1.truechoice# = userchoice# then t0.creditpertrue else -negperfalse end) as User_Test_Points
        from test t0 left join   
            question t1 on (t0.test# = t1.test#) left join
                user_test_question t2 on (t1.q# = t2.q#)
        where t2.uesrid is not null
        Group by t0.test#,t2.uesrid,neededcredit )
    Where Test_Results.User_Test_Points < Test_Results.neededcredit )
```

Comment: thanks.can you explain your code? and i don't think that we can use case when or is null.

Comment: my fault, I thought the query was to t-sql.
You should find equivalents for these sentences with your SQL engine.

Sub-query (Select t0.test# ... group by t0.test#, t2.uesrid, neededcredit), I use to get the actual score for each test user and also get the 'neededcredit':

sub-query (Select userid from ... ) that includes the previous sub-query, I get the list of users who have failed some test.

Finally, I know that all users who are not in the previous list have passed all their tests.